# Автоматическое тестирование кода во встраиваемых системах

Tags: тестирование, юнит-тесты, embedded

Для приложений, выполняемых в полноценных ОС существует достаточное количество средств и алгоритмов автоматической проверки кода и его тестирования. Думаю, многие слышали о юнит-тестировании, статическом анализе и аналогичных вещах.

Интересно, есть ли подобные программы и методы в применении ко встраиванмым системам? Там дюже много особенностей, требующих и внимания, и контроля. Тем более, что программа взаимодействует напрямую со внешней средой, которую физически так просто не сэмулируешь.
Но хочется быть уверенным, что код достойно обработает любую ситуацию и не изменит своего поведения при глубоких модернизациях его же.

UPD: проверяторы общего назначения ориентированы несколько на другие проблемы, да и связанные иногда с конкретной платформой (откуда им знать, какого размера стандартные типы, например), не нужен анализ динамического использования памяти (обычно используются или статика, или стек)... В то же время они и понятия не имеют о среде выполнения (разрядность, прерывания, нестандартные стандартные библиотеки, раздельные шины и т.д.), всяких компиляторных "наворотах" и подобном.

Опять же, можно гонять функции на спецтестах, но как их организовать в проекте и как отслеживать результаты? Особенно, если память и так на исходе?

Comment: Эмм, в QNX же вроде есть графический интерфейс, остается только подключить к плате монитор и оттестировать все с использованием местного софта, наверное есть умельцы которые уже написали под это дело профайлеры, статистические анализаторы кода, дизассемблеры и.т.д и.т.п

Comment: Думаю, что разницы нет - `C/C++` везде одинаковый. Разница кроется в процессе - в команде, которая пишет что-то для системы реального времени вам никто не даст сделать глубокую модернизацию без предварительно обсуждения на недельку и кучи `code review`. Ну или даст, но тогда сильно увеличиваются шансы стать вторым Фобос-Грунтом.

Comment: Я про более мелкие проекты, где даже нет полноценной ОС, максимум осрв без гуя и т.д. Или нет ОС в принципе. Дизассемблеры, профайлеры, отладчики есть. А вот о статанализе/тестировании не слыхал вообще. Cortex-mX, AVRx (хотя бы из-за его архитектуры памяти), 51 и т.д.

Comment: @Алексей Сонькин 
Ну там же вроде сначала делают на эмуляторе, потом вставляют в отладочную плату, потом в реальное устройство во время этих трех этапов есть очень много возможностей к всесторонней проверке кода.

Comment: А мне нравится вопрос. Я бы почитал ответы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если за три года никто их так и не написал, значит и почитать, увы, не удастся.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: да, а жаль )